# O tipo adequado para servir JavaScript é "text/javascript" ou "application/x-javascript" ou "application/javascript"?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, tipo-de-conteúdo

Ao analisar o código fonte de diversas páginas, constata-se que os cabeçalhos referentes ao Javascript variam no que respeita ao [*mime*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> indicado, mas fica a duvida sobre qual devemos efetivamente utilizar:

Como usamos em HTML para indicar um [bloco de Javascript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

```
text/javascript
```

Com denotação de aplicação via:

```
application/x-javascript
```

ou

```
application/javascript
```

## Pergunta

Qual o *mime* correto a enviar quando estamos a servir Javascript? Pós e Contras do seu uso?

Comment: Faltou citar quando não são especificados, tendo apenas `<script></script>`

Comment: @Orion Esse caso é outra "guerra", aqui refiro-me mesmo a _http-headers_, dai ter aplicado a tag ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O tipo "correto" é `application/javascript` segundo o [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) (`text/javascript` é obsoleto). Mas os browsers modernos conseguem entender todos eles. A razão pela qual "application" é o correto é que o browser irá executar o código JavaScript, e ele não precisa ser lido (como texto) - por exemplo, um JS minificado não é legível (na maioria dos casos), mas pode ser executado sem problemas.

Em outras palavras, se você quer ser exato, e usar o tipo MIME recomendado, então você deve usar `application/javascript`. Eu coloquei o termo "correto" acima entre aspas de propósito - todos (pelo que eu saiba) os browsers modernos irão tratar a resposta a uma requisição iniciada por um `<script src=...>` como JavaScript, independente do valor do Content-Type na resposta dos servidores.

No entanto, pode ser que no futuro algum browser mais estrito seja criado, ou que algum furo de segurança seja detectado e que faça que os browsers obrigarem o uso do tipo MIME "correto", então começar a usar o tipo correto agora pode economizar dor de cabeça depois.

Comment: Olá. Na boa, eu não uso nenhum pois nunca me preocupei de fato com isso. Existe algum ganho nisso ou é apenas perfumaria? Dá uma enriquecida na sua resposta,

Comment: Se você quer ser pedântico, e usar o tipo MIME recomendado, então você deve usar `application/javascript`. Eu coloquei o termo "correto" entre aspas de propósito na resposta - todos (pelo que eu saiba) os browsers modernos irão tratar a resposta a uma requisição iniciada por um `<script src=...>` como JavaScript, independente do valor do `Content-Type` na resposta dos servidores.

Comment: No entanto, pode ser que no futuro algum browser mais pedântico seja criado, ou que algum furo de segurança seja detectado e que faça que os browsers obrigarem o uso do MIME "correto", então começar a usar o tipo correto agora pode economizar dor de cabeça depois.

Comment: Justo, argumento aceito. Acho que seria legal você complementar sua resposta com esses detalhes, só pra ficar bonito.

Comment: Eu ia fazer um comentário não relacionado ao _mime-type_ aqui, mas tenho medo de soar pedante.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck, adicionei os comentários à resposta.